# FATAL_ERROR System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set

Tags: apex, json

I want to run a class where it calls the static resource and input the values in the object.
I have a Static Resource name Interest_Tag MIME Type application/json in following JSON format

```
[
     {
        "NAME": "Healthcare",
        "COGNITIVE_UNIQUE_ID": 10622212216
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Real Estate",
        "UNIQUE_ID": "106ff12216"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Investigo",
        "UNIQUE_ID": 12516177889
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Verna",
        "UNIQUE_ID": "agagagha1215"
      }
    ]
```

My Class

```
public class InterestTags_Insert {

    public static void InterestTags_Insert1(){
        List <DevNiks__Interest_Tag__c> IT = new List<DevNiks__Interest_Tag__c>();
        StaticResource sr= [select id,body from StaticResource Where Name = 'Interest_Tag'];
        String allcontents = sr.body.toString();
        system.debug('allcontents==='+allcontents);

        String str = JSON.serialize(allcontents);
        system.debug('New String = '+str);



         List<StaticResource_InterestTags> StaticResource_InterestTagsResults = (List<StaticResource_InterestTags>)JSON.deserialize(str, List<StaticResource_InterestTags>.class);
        System.debug('StaticResource_InterestTags' +StaticResource_InterestTagsResults);

        for(StaticResource_InterestTags srt :StaticResource_InterestTagsResults ){
            DevNiks__Interest_Tag__c ditc = new DevNiks__Interest_Tag__c();
            ditc.name = srt.NAMEE;
            if(srt.UNIQUE_ID!=null){
            ditc.DevNiks__Unique_ID__c = String.valueof(srt.UNIQUE_ID);
            }
            IT.add(ditc);
            System.debug('IT List ==='+IT);

        }
        Database.insert(IT);

    }


}
```

My Parser Class

```
public class StaticResource_InterestTags {

    public String NAMEE;
    public Integer UNIQUE_ID;


    public static List<StaticResource_InterestTags> parse(String json) {
        return (List<StaticResource_InterestTags>) System.JSON.deserialize(json, List<StaticResource_InterestTags>.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `allcontents` is already a JSON string so you don't need to serialize it.

So replace:

```
String str = JSON.serialize(allcontents);
```

with:

```
String str = allcontents;
```

(When you serialize it, you turn the JSON representing an array into JSON representing single string value, hence the error message.)

Comment: It is throwing another error :- FATAL_ERROR System.StringException: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string

Comment: please open a new post for it, as it is a different question.

Comment: @SFDC_Nik Sounds like your static resource is _not_ a text string.

Comment: Thanks @KeithC for the help, it's working now. Static resource was a JSON file which i converted to String and then passed it. Thank you for your help.